# IEnumerable List appear empty in request command when Using mediator cqrs pattern from swagger gen

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cqrs, mediator

I have to post Circulum Vitae info to Db
for that i created a Entity Circulum vitae :

```
 public class CirculumVitae
{
    public Guid UserId { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<Skills> Skills { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public  List<Langages> Langages { get; set; }
    public string Resume { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Education> Educations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
    public  UserInfo UserInfos { get; set; }
}
```

I use Mediator CQRS pattern with asp.net core Api , so I have created a Command for Post data

```
 public class CreateCVCommand : CreateCommand
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SkillsDto> Skills { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<Langages> Langages { get; set; }
    public string Resume { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ExperienceDto> Experiences { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<EducationDto> Educations { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProjectsDto> Projects { get; set; }
    public UserInfoDto UserInfos { get; set; }

}
```

my endpoint in controller for getting data from swagger
[image]

all Enumerables Array are Empty after Try Post data from Swagger

i tied replace Enumerable by List but same problem
please Help me

Comment: What's your  Langages model ? And your Langages can get the list! Why the others cannot? What's your other model  look s like ?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are using mediator cqrs pattern, i think you are not using MediatR library for this, its recommended to use it.

You can find the link [Here](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR).

Instead of IEnumerable use List (as can be seen in your case Language count is available). An IEnumerable does not hold even the count of the items in the list, instead, you have to iterate over the elements to get the count of items.

Your command class will be similar to following:

```
using MediatR;
namespace Test
{
    public class CreateCVCommand : IRequest<CvDto>
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        
        public List<SkillsDto> Skills { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<Langages> Langages { get; set; }
        
        public string Resume { get; set; }

        public List<ExperienceDto> Experiences { get; set; }

        public List<EducationDto> Educations { get; set; }

        public List<ProjectsDto> Projects { get; set; }
        
        public UserInfoDto UserInfos { get; set; }
    }
}
```